# C# AutoMapper from DTO to Destination using dynamic property name?

Tags: c#, automapper, dto

I've looked into custom resolvers based on properties for this, but I seem to only be finding code for an older version of AutoMapper.

My use case is fairly simple at this time.  I am mapping DTOs to Domain entities using AutoMapper.

The field names on the DTOs and the Domain Entities all match for 100%, except for one field per pair, henceforth referred to as the "Key field".  I have about 20 DTO -> Domain pairings at this point, and this number will grow.

It would be nice if I could use the AutoMapper's automatic name resolution for all of the property mappings, except for the single "Key" field.

The "Key" field on the domain entity follows the convention Key, and is always a string.

The "Key" field on the DTO could be rewritten to match the Domain Entities, allowing name based mapping to be used in all cases, but I'm curious as to what the solution would be if I wanted to use PropertyInfo in my ForMember expression, or if that's even possible.

Comment: ForAllMaps + the string based ForMember/MapFrom.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use PropertyInfo. What about using AfterMap to set value for your key property:

```
class Entity
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }
}

class Dto
{
    public dynamic MyKeyProperty { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }
}

Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Entity, Dto>()
       .ForMember(nameof(Dto.MyKeyProperty), c => c.Ignore())
       .AfterMap((e, d) => { d.MyKeyProperty = $"{e.Key} ???"; });
});
```